# What is Difference between Hinduism and other religion?

Tags: puranas, gods, other-religions

What is difference between Our gods and other religion gods ?
According to Puranas

Comment: I think the premise of this question is very wrong. There cannot be other Gods (at least how other religions might define their own Gods), as per Indian scriptures. The puranas and vedas need not accept any other God, so no mention of them in any way whatsoever

Comment: @Vivikta (Indra, Agni, Shiva, Ganesha) lord

Answer (score 2):

> [Narayana Upanishad](https://www.hinduwebsite.com/vedicsection/upanishads/narayana.asp) verse 2
>
> > He is perennial. Narayana is Brahma. Narayana is Shiva. Narayana is Indra and Kaala (god of death). All directions are Narayana. All sides are Narayana. Inside and outside is Narayana. Narayana is what has happened, what is happening and what will happen. Narayana is the only God who is blemish less, stain less, order less, end less and who cannot be described and when Narayana is there, there is no other second. He who knows this, becomes himself Lord Vishnu. Thus is read, the Upanishads of Yajur Veda. Narayana Upanishad

Every thing is Narayana. You, me, time and etc.

Other religions God(almost all religions) describe God or gods to be separate from the creation but in Hinduism God itself is the creator and creation.

More like a, we all are projections of that supreme God (Narayana). [i. e monism]

That's the difference

Answer (score 2):

Other Religions(Abrahamic Religions) "God" is a person sitting on a particular place, who creates Humans to worship him and rewards them after their life based on their surrender to him. Whereas in Hinduism, Gods are attributes or powers of Mind and Brahman is a principle which underpins everything that exists and identical to your innermost self.

- **Brahman indeed was all this in the beginning** (Brihadaranyaka Up
  1.4.10), From this Atman, space came out, etc all the way to earth, plants, humans, etc. Having made the universe, he entered it, he
  became both gross and subtle, both well-defined and not-well-defined,
  both supporting and non-supporting, both conscious and
  non-conscious.(Taittirya Up 3.1-3.6)
- In the beginning the universe was Existence only, one alone
  without a second" (Chandogya Up 6.2.1), Where one sees nothing else
  (Chandogya Up 7.24.1), "**All this is but the Self**" (Chandogya Up
  7.25.2),"In the beginning all this was but the one Self" (Aitareya Up 1.1.1), and "**All this is verily Brahman**." (Chandogya Up 3.14.1)
- All this before is immortal Brahman; certainly all behind is Brahman;
  **all to the south and to the north; all bellow and all alone stretched
  out, i.e., extended, all this is certainly Brahma**n, the
  highest.(Mandukya Upanishad 2.2.11)
- **He who knows that highest Brahman becomes even Brahman**; and in his
  line, none who knows not the Brahman will be born. He crosses grief
  and virtue and vice and being freed from the knot of the heart,
  becomes immortal. (Mundaka Upanishad 3.2.9)
- **The gods are mind-born**, yoked to the mind, having the blissful power
  of discrimination (dakṣā), and are the children of
  discernment.(Taittiriya Samhita 1.2.3.2)
- **Fire, the earth, the air, the sky, the sun, heaven, the moon and the
  stars—these are the Vasus.The ten organs in the human body, with the
  mind as the eleventh are Rudras. The twelve months (are parts) of a
  year are Adityas. Strength is Indra.** The vital force Hiranyagarbha is
  Brahman. (Brihadaranyaka Upanishad 3.9.1-9)
- **What one cannot think** with the mind, **but by which they say the mind
  is made to think, know That alone to be the Brahman**, not this which
  people here worship.(Kena Upanishad 2.1.5)
- The mind is Brahman—this worship is called adhyātma. Next is that
  called adhidaivata: Space is Brahman. That is, meditate on space as
  Brahman. These two ways of meditation are advised: adhyātma and
  adhidaivata.(Chandogya Upanishad 3.18.1)
- **This self was indeed Brahman in the beginning. It knew only itself as
  ‘I am Brahmaṇ**.’ Therefore It became all. **And whoever among the Gods
  knew It all became That**; and the same with sages and so on. The sage
  Vāmadeva, while realising that his self as That, knew, ‘I was Manu,
  and the Sun. And to this day whoever in like manner knows It as, ‘I
  am Brahman,’ becomes all **While who worships another god thinking, ‘He
  is one, and I am another,’ is like an animal to the
  gods**(Brihadaranyaka 1.4.10)
- **The Self alone is all the gods; everything subsists in the Self** it is
  the Self that brings about the connection of these embodied beings
  with actions.(Manu 12.119)
- **This some people call ‘Agni’; others, ‘Manu-Prajāpati’; others,
  ‘Indra’; others, ‘Prāṇa**’; and yet others, ‘the Eternal Brahman.(Manu
  12.123)
- From the waters, which are the body of Vishnu, was produced the
  lotus-shaped earth, with its seas and mountains. The stars are
  Vishnu; the galaxies are Vishnu; forests, mountains, regions, rivers,
  oceans are Vishnu: he is all that is, all that is not. **He, the lord,
  is identical with consciousness, through which he is all forms, but
  is not a substance.** You must recognise therefore that the mountains,
  oceans, and all the diversities of earth and the universe, are
  illusions of apprehension.(Vishnu Purana 2.12.36)

Comment: Can you tell according to puranas

Comment: Dear @PashamVishnuVardhanGoud , I spent 45 minutes writing it. Please have a look at it. I have covered Puranic concepts also.

Comment: If you want me to just write on Puranas then it will be a huge task. Ask a separate question , I will write another answer.

Comment: You can answer according to puranas

Comment: Where?You want me to write another bunch of 10 quotes here??

Comment: You can email me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120658/discussion-between-sethu-srivatsa-koduru-and-pasham-vishnu-vardhan-goud).