# Panchayata puja in vaishava puranas?

Tags: advaita, bhagavata-purana, adi-shankaracharya, vishnu-purana

Do Vishnu Purana
(or) bhagavatam tells about panchayata puja
About five god worship which is given by adivata and Adi shankaracharya
Padma purana tells about five god worship like that Vishnu Purana and bhagavatam(any one can tell according to shridhara Swany tika also) tell about five god worship

Comment: Mahabharata the Epic speaks about it. Shall I write the answer?

Comment: You can give answer

Comment: I am writing the answer. What I have been observing is , many questions I have given lot of time (Say 30 Mins) and effort and you don't even upvote and accept answers. Kindly dont do that. If you accept and upvote answers, your points will also increase. If you dont do it, why ask questions then? Just saying-Dont take it in wrong way bro

Comment: @Sethu Srivatsa Koduru bro, what you have beeen observing about the - "hard written answers not getting the appropriate upvotes" is TRUE , which is also True for the questions as well! For example :- See this question itself. YOU yourself gave a satisfactory answer to this question, yet you yourself didn't consider it worthy enough to give it an Upvote yourself? **We must maybe try to make it a two way road (*VOTE BOTH ON GOOD QUESTIONS ASKED AND GOOD ANSWERS PROVIDED*), and contribute and not compete, to have an enriching experience in here on this HSE!** (No offense though).

Comment: I have upvoted many worthy questions and answers bro. I only dowvoted once for the question "What is Ravana Gita"
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/45070/19211
See this answer
Many such answers. I end up writing so much when he asks, He doesnt even upvote or accept answers. Even Archit has told this to somebody else. It hurts when guys change Qn immediately after we write for 30-40 mins and don't even accept our answer!

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru, yes that I can also see. Answer is not being accepted at all. That's maybe kind of sad. Maybe one needs to be better toured about the site and how to use it properly.

Comment: He edited the question later to Puranas and in Chat Box I told him all that he wants. He neither upvoted nor accepted. It isn't the first time. He has done it many times. Lol he didn't even upvote even one answer so far of anyone answering his own qns or from different qns! @Vivikta

Comment: Well, good luck with that then, @SethuSrivatsaKoduru, :p.  Maybe this should be the mantra in this case then, [**कर्मण्येवाधिकारस्ते मा फलेषु कदाचन।**](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=2&field_nsutra_value=47&htrskd=1&etsiva=1&choose=1)

Comment: @Vivikta 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Vishnu Purana and Bhagavatam don't have any explicit referece for the panchayatana puja concept, it is found other Vaishnava Puranas.

**Naradiya Purana III.65.44-47:-**

> *यदा मध्ये यजेद्विष्णुं बाह्यादिषु विनायकम् ।। रविं शिवां शिवं चैव यदा मध्ये तु शङ्करम् ।। ६५-४४ ।। रविं गणेशमंबां च हरिं चाथ यदा शिवाम् ।।
> ईशं विघ्नार्कगोविंदान्मध्ये चेद्गणनायकम् ।। ६५-४५ ।। शिवं शिवां रविं
> विष्णुं रवौ मध्यगते पुनः ।। गणेषं विष्णुमंबां च शिवं चेति यथाक्रमम् ।।
> ६५-४६ ।। एवं नित्य समभ्यर्च्य देवपञ्चकमादृतः ।। ब्राह्मे मुहूर्त्ते
> ह्युत्थाय कृत्वाचा वश्यकं बुधः ।। ६५-४७ ।।*

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Mahabharata speaks of only one Spirit Prevading this universe who takes forms of all 5 Deities of Panchayata Puja.

> Know that this entire universe is under the control of one divine
> Being. The Veda that is in the soul regards the unity of various
> creatures. When a living creature realizes this unity in consequence
> of true knowledge, he is then said to attain to Brahman.(Mahabharata
> Santi Parva Section CCLXXX)
>
> There is but one Brahman which is Truth’s self. It is from ignorance
> of that One, that god-heads have been conceived to be diverse.
> (Mahabharata, Udyoga Parva, Section 43)
>
> The Supreme Spirit hath three condition, In the form of Brahma, he is
> the Creator, and in the form of Vishnu he is the Preserver, and in his
> form as Rudra, he is the Destroyer of the Universe.(Mahabharata Vana
> Parva Section CCLXX)
>
> Narada said, ‘**Thou art He who is the topic of the five foremost of
> scriptures (viz., those that appertain to the worship of Surya, of
> Sakti, of Ganesa, of Siva, and of Vishnu**). (Mahabharata Santi Parva
> Section CCCXXXIX)

Comment: This verse is a wrong translation by KMG. Sanskrit verses of mahabharata shanti parva don't mention panchayatana or five gods. "Five foremost of scriptures" doesn't mean five gods. It means five systems mentioned in narayaniya i.e. vedas, samkhya, yoga, pancharatra, pashupata - https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12c049.htm